# How to convert string to object in object in js?

Tags: javascript, json, string, object

I have a string: 'lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet'
And I want to write a function with a parameter that converts this string passed as a parameter to an object like this:

```
{
     lorem:{
       ipsum:{
         dolor:{
           sit:{
             amet: []
           }
         }
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to create a nested object given an array of keys](/q/50287167/4642212) (provided you know about `string.split(",")`).

Answer (score 2):

Split the string, and use `Array.reduceRight()` to generate the object:

```js
const fn = (str, param) =>
  str.split(',')
   .reduceRight((acc, key) => ({ [key]: acc }), param)

const str = 'lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet'

const result = fn(str, [])

console.log(result)
```